# How can I combine these two Gulp tasks into a single one?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

Right now I have two tasks: `templates` and `js`. `templates` has to run first so that changes are be picked up by `js`. I want to combine these, eliminating the intermediate file, so that the task works like this:

1. Compile and concatenate templates into a single chunk of JS
2. Concatenate that chunk with the rest of my application's JS code
3. Output the whole thing as a single file

How can I do this?

Here's my current code:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var handlebars   = require('gulp-handlebars');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var wrap         = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare      = require('gulp-declare');

// Compile Handlebars templates into JS
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  return gulp.src('./templates/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
        handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'templates',
        noRedeclare: true,
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});

// Concatenate and minify application JS
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
```

Answer (score -1):

For me the easyest and cleaner way is to call one task after the other with

```
gulp.task('js', ['templates'], function(){
....
```

In this way the js task need the execution of templates task

Keeping the compilation and the final concat in 2 separate task it's not that bad for me.

Let me know if it's not a viable solution for you

**EDIT**

in one single task you can try to use merge-stream

and do

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');
gulp.task('templates', function() {
  var jsStream = gulp.src('./js/*.js')
   .pipe(concat('all.js'));
  var templateStream = gulp.src('./templates/*.hbs')
    .pipe(handlebars({
        handlebars: require('handlebars')
    }))
    .pipe(wrap('Handlebars.template(<%= contents %>)'))
    .pipe(declare({
        namespace: 'templates',
        noRedeclare: true,
    }))
    .pipe(concat('templates.js'));

    merge(jsStream, templateStream)
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});
```

I've done it by heart without trying so my not work as intended

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the intermediate file, named templates.js in this case. I am trying to do it the Gulp way and do it all in memory until final output.

Comment: I'm assuming you have other files than template.js in ./js/ am I right?